# reinitialize processing.js sketch after ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, processing.js

I would like to refire the styling and processing.js scripts that i linked to in the head so that they display correctly when brought in through an ajax-request. I see where in the ajax request this code needs to be, but i don't know how to tell the code to simply reapply the script. I've seen people using getScript() to do this, but from what i can tell this reloads the script, rather than simply telling it repeat or refire. Do all of the scripts need their own reinitialization? I found the syntax highlighters .highlight() method, but i am yet to get the processing script to load. currently, `Processing.loadSketchFromSources($('#processing'), ['mysketch.pde']);` does not work. I am using current versions of all libraries. Surprised i haven't been able to find the answer yet, as a lot of people seem to have the same problem. Thanks for your help!

index page:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // put all your jQuery here.

        //Check if url hash value exists (for bookmark)
    $.history.init(pageload);   
        //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');
        //Search for link with REL set to ajax
    $('a[rel=ajax]').live("click",function(){
                //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;
                //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
                //for back button
        $.history.load(hash);   
                //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
                //hide the content and show the progress bar
        //$('#content').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
        //run the ajax
        getPage();
        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        return false;

    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $('#loading').hide();   

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#content').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#content').fadeIn('fast');
            //reapply styles?

            //apply syntax highlighting. this works
            SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
//relaod processing sketch, currently displays nothing
            Processing.loadSketchFromSources($('#processing'), ['mysketch.pde']);
        }       
    });
}
```

This the ajax-loaded content:

```
    <!--ajax'd content-->
    <??>
    <h2>code</h2>
    <pre class="brush: php">
    $last_modified = filemtime("header.php");
    echo("last modified: ");
    echo(date("m.j.y h:ia", $last_modified));
    </pre>
    <script type="application/processing">
    </script>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="mysketch.pde" id="processing">
    </canvas>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<??>
```

Comment: You can add your code now, answers will never come otherwise...

Comment: Seconded, still: if you have some JS than runs before the Ajax request and then you add something to the DOM, obviously it will be unaffected by the previous code.

Comment: so i guess my question is how do i make the .js fire again? i might be able to figure that out by myself.

Answer (score 3):

So, let's analyze what usually happens when you include an (external or internal) Javascript code: It will automatically execute only the code that is available in the global scope. "Good" scripts will only add one command to the global scope which will then execute the initialization code somewhere in a function/method.

All you need to do is view the external Javascript file and find out what is being executed from the global scope. There is no general answer to that ... some scripts use an object and call its init() method ... but that is totally subject to the imagination of the developer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have javascript that needs to trigger, you MUST add this to the head element:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = "your AJAX-obtained js code";
head.appendChild(script);
```

The same trick goes for CSS. Add a  element to the head with your CSS declarations as innerHTML. So: make sure to preprocess your AJAX response and split out the JavaScript and CSS elements, then add those to the document header. It's probably easier to make your response a JSON object along the lines of:

```
{
    html: "<html>string<goes>here</goes></html>",
    scripts: ["url1","url2","url2",...],
    style: ...
}
```

and then parsing that JSON for the html (which you use as innerHTML for a new document.createElement("div") or something, and then append wherever it needs appending), the scripts (which you turn into  elements for HEAD insertion) and the style declarations (which you turn into  elements for HEAD insertion).

(On a functional note, your example AJAX response looks like it has PHP code in it. I have no idea what you're using it for, but that looks like a bad response)

Comment: I'm confused. My 'response' is a php page, not that this page currently interacts with a server, but i would like it to someday. also confused by what you mean by "your ajax obtained code" or why i would want an html string, i'm already getting the correct page. also i have never messed with JSON, is it necessary for this? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for your response to be contain PHP code, since a browser doesn't "do" PHP. Things like "$var" and "echo" are just text strings, the browser will do nothing with them, so they're not going to contribute to anything processing.js or styling related.

If you want to refresh processing.js and styling based on content obtained via an AJAX request, you have to get the right response back: a response that is neatly separated as html (for in the body), css styling (for <style> insertion in the head), and script code (for <script> insertion in the head) is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone stumbles upon this:

If you have `processing.js` already loaded, simply call `Processing.reload()` in your AJAX success/complete function.

Comment: This is required to make the script run I take it?

Comment: Yes this will run the initialiser to run the sketch from the `.pde` file specified in the `data-processing-sources` attribute of your `canvas`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you already have an element with `id="processing"` on your page.  In that case `$("#processing")` will only return the first one.  If that is the case, change the id or use a class instead.

The other option, which I don't recommend, is to use `$("[id=processing]")`.  That will return every element on the page with `id="processing"`.  But, don't use it.  Use unique ids in your page, or switch to using classes, whichever works best for you.

Comment: that is a neat trick but didn't solve my dilemma. The sketch displays fine when i go to code.php, but never displays when i navigate to it by ajax, even if everything it requires to run is in the page. This makes me think something in the ajax request is breaking it.